# Android app to get and send location data continuously in every 2 mins even device is sleeping

Tags: java, android, location

Is it possible to get and send (via http req.) location data continuously in every 2 mins even device is sleeping? I tried more solutions but they stops working after (several minutes) device goes down to sleep.

Comment: Doze mode, app standby, and manufacturer-specific battery-saver modifications will interfere with what you are trying to do. For short periods (say, under an hour), you could use a foreground service and a partial wakelock.

Comment: You need to release the wakelock when you are done with it.

Comment: You also need to hold onto the `WakeLock` object.

Comment: @CommonsWare
 So it is not possible to develop such app which continuously send location data (even it is sleeping or in stand-by). Based on your comment it is not possible...